# Powershell Group-Object and sum up

Tags: powershell

i have a csv file with following informations and want to use powershell to reach my goal.
Every month i create this report and i want to group it and sum up the total pages.

| Date & Time | Full Name | Printer Name | Total Pages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21.10.2021 17:15:15 | User One | Printer HP | 13 |
| 21.10.2021 17:25:34 | User One | Printer Dell | 5 |
| 21.10.2021 17:38:05 | User Two | Printer HP | 9 |

In the end, i want to see which user printed on what printer how many total pages over a month.

So i use the group-object 'Full Name',Printer Name' but how can i sum up the total pages according to that group?

Best regards,
Manuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measure-Object can be used to sum, average, minimum and maximum

```
Import-Csv C:\ps\sampled.csv | Group-Object 'Full Name' | 
Select-Object 'Name', @{ n='Total Pages'; e={ ($_.Group | Measure-Object 'Total Pages' -Sum).Sum } }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the missing link for me. My code now looks like that:

Import-CSV 'C:\temp\Print job.csv' | Group-Object 'Full Name','Printer Name' | Select-Object 'Name', @{ n='Total Pages'; e={ ($_.Group | Measure-Object 'Total Pages' -Sum).Sum } }